# Will it be incorrect if I pluralize 'mouse' to 'mouses' when it's of a computer?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

We all know that *mouse* is *mice* when pluralized. But I wanted to instruct my fellow mate to replace *mouses* as they weren't working.

The *mouse* there is of a computer.

I think it's a computer product and therefore may not follow the rules of English. Rather, it would be 'mouses' only.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that mice vs mouses in the computer sense is still an open issue as the [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/mice-mouses/) 
 suggests in the following extract. Apparently mice is  more common  than mouses but both forms are used:

> For the small device used to guide the cursor on a computer display, ***many dictionaries endorse both mice and mouses as the plural form, and few usage and style guides offer a definitive preference (exception: AP says “mice”)***.
>
> ***We assumed mouses was standard for the computer device, but we were wrong***. Searches of current news articles reveal 31 instances of “computer mice” to only seven of “computer mouses.” And on the whole web, Google finds nearly 10 million results for “computer mice” to only around 200,000 for “computer mouses.”
>
> These ratios might be skewed by a greater tendency to use “computer” with “mice” to avoid confusion with the rodent. But this may be partially offset by instances of mouses as a simple-present verb (e.g., she mouses over the image). ***In any case, we can safely say that mices prevails by a large margin.***

Please see also [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=computer%20mouses%2Ccomputer%20mice&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20mouses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomputer%20mice%3B%2Cc0): computer mice vs computer mouses.

The more common usage of mice vs mouses is confirmed also by ODO:

[Usage](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/):

> - Is the plural of mouse in the computing sense mice or mouses? People often feel that this sense needs its own distinctive plural, but in fact the ordinary plural mice is commoner, and the first recorded use of the term in the plural (1984) is mice

Note that the AHD lists both versions:

[mouse:](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=mouse)

> - ***pl. mice or mous·es (mous′iz)*** Computers A handheld, button-activated input device that when rolled along a flat surface directs an indicator to move correspondingly about a computer screen, allowing the operator to move the indicator freely, as to select operations or manipulate text or graphics.

and curiously

> - the Garner’s Dictionary of Modern American Usage, prefers “mouses.” His reasoning is pretty sound: for the plural of “louse,” we use “lice” for more than one insect, but “louses” for more than one cad.

Comment: Sorry to intervene here – and you can delete this again if you really want to, I suppose – but this is one of the more exemplary and well-researched answers I've seen on ELL. I think it should (and hope it can) remain in our archives of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Software companies use the phrase "mouse devices" so as to avoid any confusion in plural form. But most of the Mouse Manufacturers refer them as "mice", although it is probably a case of personal preference until there is an official ruling on it.

Comment: Eitehr you call such a thing a *device* or you name it! Both together...uhh not sure! :)

Comment: ...and since English is descriptively defined and there's no person or organisation with the authority to make an "official ruling", it's personal preference *forever* unless you're working for an organisation whose house style specifies which to use. That, or you accept that the current consensus is "mice" and that's as official as it's ever going to get.